# Background indexing MongoDB on server

Tags: ssh, mongodb

I have a collection on a server containing ~23 million documents.  I need to index this collection and obviously this will take a long time.  If I run this indexing operation with `background: true` while using the mongo shell through ssh on the server, if I then close the ssh session with that shell query running, will the operation continue to run?

EDIT for more info:
e.g if I have

```
> db.journeys.ensureIndex({startStationName: 1}, {background:true})
```

This blocks further queries in that session.  I know that I can start a new session and access the db as `background:true` but if I close this session (I can't keep my laptop connected to the internet for the 30+ hours this query will take), will the indexing operation continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a background build is initiated, it will be a background process.

The reason why the shell is blocking is to give you a feedback. You can safely quit the ssh session.

Comment: Thanks, have tested and can verify that this is working. The indexing continues even if I close the session where I initiated.  It turned out I didn't need screen or tmux so I've selected this as the answer rather than Janne's input

Comment: for reference, you can check to see if the index build is still running on the `mongod` by running db.currentOp() from the `mongo` shell or by looking in the logs for that instance (it will log index build progress periodically and give you a percentage completion figure).

Comment: Thanks, I discovered this yesterday and my indexing is now happily running on the server in the background (currently at 30% after 24 hours -_-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `screen` or `tmux` and be worry-free?

Comment: Sure, I could even just access the server with a new tab on my local terminal but that's not what I'm asking, edited my question to try and make it a bit clearer.

Comment: If you run Mongo shell inside `screen` or `tmux` session, Mongo shell sure remains running even if your laptop says Kaboom. You can re-attach to screen/tmux session later from whatever device you want. What part of your question I misunderstood?

Comment: Oh sorry it seems I misunderstood your answer as I'm not familiar with those tools, thanks for the info